# Exercise 8.3 - Consistency Intro to logic Stanford course

Tags: logic

I am trying to solve [this exercise](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/exercises/exercise_08_03.html):

> Consider a version of the Blocks World with just three blocks - a, b,
> and c. The on relation is axiomatized below.
>
> ¬ on(a,a)         on(a,b)     ¬   on(a,c) ¬   on(b,a)     ¬   on(b,b)         on(b,c)
> ¬ on(c,a)     ¬   on(c,b)     ¬   on(c,c)
>
> Let's suppose that the relation "above" is defined as follows.
>
> ∀x.∀z.(above(x,z) ⇔ on(x,z) ∨ ∃y.(above(x,y) ∧ above(y,z)))
>
> A sentence φ is consistent with a set Δ of sentences if and only if
> there is a truth assignment that satisfies all of the sentences in Δ ∪
> {φ}. Say whether each of the following sentences is consistent with
> the sentences about on and above shown above. Be careful. It's tricky.
>
> above(a,a)
>
> above(c,a)

I tried the following with the first statement:

Since on(a,a) is false, then we must see if there is a y such that
above(a,y) ∧ above(y,a) is true. in the case that y is b.
then both above(a,b) and above(b,a) must be true.

We examine above(b,a) since above(a,b) is known to be true,
and since on(b,a) is false then both above(b,c) and above(c,a) have to be true.

We examine above(c,a) since above(b,c) is known to be true,
and since on(c,a) is false then both above(c,b) and above(b,a) have to be true.

So we need to examine above(b,a)... and we end up where we started.

I also tried with y is c and the problem persists.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can prove the consistency of the statements above.

Comment: Heh, naming a relation "above" had me confused for a moment, when you reference "the above relation," which usually means "a recently referenced relation." It might be good to put "above" in quotes in English sentences.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews noted, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining $\text{above}(a,b)$ as always being true is consistent with all the assumptions stated in the problem.  It is an infinite recursion.  Or you could check all $2^{3 \times 3}$ possible values of "above" like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a4c24a44da8ab67be5413ff353278ab

There are 148 of the possible 512 definitions of above that are consistent with the propositions in the problem.

---

Start with the axiom:

$$\text{above}(x,y) = \text{true}$$

It should apparent that this (ignoring everything else in the problem) is consistent.  Then check that it is consistent with the definition of "above".

$$\forall x,z.\text{above}(x,z) \iff (\text{on}(x,z) \lor \exists y.(\text{above}(x,y) \land \text{above}(y,z)))$$

$$\forall x,z.\text{true} \iff (\text{on}(x,z) \lor \exists y.(\text{true} \land \text{true}))$$

$$\forall x,z.\text{true} \iff (\text{on}(x,z) \lor \text{true})$$

$$\forall x,z.\text{true} \iff \text{true}$$

$$\text{true}$$

Note that this is the case no matter how "on" is defined.  So the next thing is to check that the definition of "on" is consistent, which is clearly is because it is just assigning a value to 9 different variables.

Then it is also easy to see that $\text{above}(a,a) = \text{true}$ and $\text{above}(c,a) = \text{true}$ so no contradiction derived from that either.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but how can I prove the consistency of above(a,a)
and
above(c,a) from the given axiom and the ground statements ? that is my question

Comment: @A.S. Ok edited to be more clear.

Comment: I see, thank you again, but that's the case if we have an axiom saying above(x,y)=true
, in this case we don't .... so ... what should we do ? how can I find out what above(a,a) and above(c,a) are ?

Comment: @A.S. Do you know what "consistent" means?

Comment: yes .. at least one truth assignment satisfies all the statements, I apologize if my previous question is kind of stupid but I honestly don't get it

Comment: That's a good enough definition (it isn't quite right but works in most cases).  The "axiom" is a truth assignment for "above".  It is what satisfies all the other statements.  Think of "above" as being a variable.  Or being 9 variables, each possible value of above(x, y).

Comment: I see, it didn't occur to me to put a truth assignment to the "above" relation because I thought it can only be defined by the on relation and the axiom stated in the original problem, that what I understood from the question ,thank you a lot for the clarification though

Comment: meaning that I thought I should resolve the above relation to the on relation using the axiom, and that where the problem occured

Comment: how to know when it's not and when it is the case though ?